# How can i scale 1 side of the mesh?

Tags: modeling

I try make a model of a bottle, i started the shape from a bezier circle, though the bottle got a rounded, squared look. Extruded it up to the top of the bottle. The problem is that this bottle is not symmetric on both sides so i need in some way to scale only 1 side of the bottle, i just dont know howto. I include a photo of my blender. Would be very glad if some one could tell how to do this. I am new to blender, so this might not be best way to start with a bezier circle? Also glad for advices.[image]

Comment: Is it question about proportional editing modes? Have you tried any of them? Square root mode should be just about right if you will be moving/resizing single vertex of the side.

Answer (score 1):

Place the 3D cursor on one of the vertex on the opposite side of the mesh, press <kbd>.</kbd> to transform around the 3D cursor, and optionally press <kbd>O</kbd> to turn on *Proportional Edit* mode.

Select one of the top or two top edge loops (as prefered) and scale them with <kbd>S</kbd>

[image: Scale loop]

Comment: He may be to humble to ask but if you like his answer be sure to accept it so stack exchange knows how to archive our Q&A